# firebase hosting not displaying the correct file contents

Tags: firebase, google-play, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host a assetlinks.json file for a PWA on firebase, The issue is that I am unable to view the content of the file. I think it has something to do with my firebase.json file. The link I am trying to get is
https://bionomichealth.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
and it contains:

```
    [
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "xyz.appmaker.flvhwm",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["83:AE:08:45:58:C6:08:16:69:1E:80:50:31:84:1E:B9:55:AF:CC:4F:A9:20:B3:D5:58:B1:6A:D1:E1:27:B3:F7"]
    }
  }
]
```

and finally, here is my filebase.json:

```
    {
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "destination": "assets/assetlinks.json"
      },
      {
        "source": "/public/**",
        "destination": "/public.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

as you can see, I have my assetlink.json in my assets folder. When I navigate to the file, All i get is:

```
[ ]
```

and When I attempted to deploy the pwa to the Playstore I got a suspended notice as google thinks that I am not the owner of the pwa.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work so my best guess would be the empty version is what's actually been deployed.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Looks like firebase hosting rewrite doesn't work with `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` as source

Comment: same issue here, anyone resolved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ran into the same issue as well, it turns out you don't need to rewrite, just put it under .well-knwon under the "dist" folder after your app is built.
example also contain ios file

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "main", 
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**/apple-app-site-association",
        "destination": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ 
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [ {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-store"
        },
        {
          "key": "Expires",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "key": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        } ]
      },
      {
        "source":"**/.well-known/**",
        "headers":[{
          "key":"Content-Type",
          "value":"application/json"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the reason ios needs re-write is because they dont append .json while doing the get call, also they require the header of the response to be content-type:application/json

Comment: didn't work for me. i wanted to remove url from apk (twa)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, too, and Zhang Bruce's answer worked well for me.
To support that, for somebody who uses **React** and **Firebase** like me.

1. put **.well-known folder including  assetlinks.json file** under **public** folder

[image]

2. don't need to edit 'rewrite' in firbase.json
3. npm run build, firebase deploy --only hosting

Finally, you can see the content of the file from your hosting url as well as localhost.